# Does prosthesis exist on Ravnica?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, ravnica

On the world of Ravnica, the Simic guild are prolific biomancers who can re-grow limbs.

But given that one of the previous guildmasters created Experiment Kraj, I can imagine not everyone on Ravnica is keen on this idea.

Is there any history of prosthesis originating on Ravnica, or is all medicine for missing limbs subsumed into Simic Biomancy?

Comment: A few cards, such as [Doomed Artisan](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=470549) and [Fallen Shinobi](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=464148), show prosthesis being used in (relatively) mundane ways, but don't specifically reference as being from Ravnica or in a Ravnica-based guild. Would something like that be what you're looking for?

Comment: @giter specific to Ravnica.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for certain, but the wikis for the [material](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Cytoplast) and [guild master](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Momir_Vig) mention that the only people who would undergo the surgery for regrowing limbs, among other possible improvements, are "Simic members and people requiring prosthetics". The material, Cytoplast, also mentions that it was invented by the guild master, Momir Vig. Based on this, I would assume that there were prosthetic limbs in the years before that point.

I will note that going through the sources on the wiki, I could not find a reference to prosthetic limbs. As a result, I can't be certain that was not just an assumption that was made and added to both wiki pages.